# push and pop of integers to stack, what outcome is not possible

Tags: java, algorithm, assembly, data-structures, stack

I am trying to take an online course of algorithms and i cant seem to get my head around how this works. (this is not homework, just a question from a free online course)

would anyone explain to me how the answers are found? the are given at the end of the exercise but i do not understand how it works. thanks in advance ! :)

Suppose that an intermixed sequence of (stack) push and pop operations are performed. The pushes push the integers 0 through 9 in order; the pops print out the return value. Which of the following sequence(s) could not occur?
(a)  4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5

(b)  4 6 8 7 5 3 2 9 0 1

(c)  2 5 6 7 4 8 9 3 1 0

(d)  4 3 2 1 0 5 6 7 8 9

(e)  1 2 3 4 5 6 9 8 7 0

(f)  0 4 6 5 3 8 1 7 2 9

(g)  1 4 7 9 8 6 5 3 0 2

(h)  2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 9 0

Correct Answers: (b), (f), and (g).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: At any point, you can only do 1 of 2 things, 1 of which prints something, so it's pretty obvious what you should do at any given step to end up with the desired output.

Comment: I would disagree.  It's a programming theory question, in that it requires the individual to understand an important data structure; a stack or LIFO.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer A question that directly seeks to understand how stacks work could potentially be fine, but this question is more about simple logic than it is about how stacks work (even if that logic requires an understanding of stacks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF the numbers are pushed in order, even with the pops occurring randomly, there are certain things that can never happen. Consider (b):

Push 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, pop 4, push 5, 6, pop 6, push 7, push 8, pop 8, pop 7, pop 5, pop 3, pop 2, push 9, pop 9....  You can't pop 0 because the one is in the way.

The same is true of the other incorrect answers.

Comment: thank you. what i had to do to understand this was simply use a pen and a sheet of paper and write the process down. makes much sense now and is so easy once you understand it. thanks again :)